# I have to join two complex queries to have one result set

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I have two complex queries and i need both of their result set in one table. the problem is that one has a cte and the other don't. I dont understand the queries very much because it was written by someone else.

```
union 
convert cte to subquery
SELECT DISTINCT
         CodeFoyer,
         CodeOuvrage,
         LibDomaine,
         LIB_OUVRAGECAT,
         --POSE_OUVRAGE,
         ACCES_OUVRAGE,
         --DIVERS_OUVRAGE,
         --OBSERVATION_OUVRAGE,
         LIB_REGIME,
         VOIEENT_VOIE,
         --NUMVOIE_OUVRAGE,
         NATURE_VOIE,
         LIB_VOIE,
         LIB_VOIEDOM,
         LIB_SECTEUR,
         LIB_REGION_TECHNIQUE,
         LIB_REGION_ADMIN,
         COD_LUMINAIRE,
         LIB_LUMINAIRE,
         LIB_FOURNISSEUR_LUMINAIRE,
         XLUMELEC,
         COD_LAMPE,
         LIB_LAMPE,
         LIB_LAMPEFAM,


    Ordre,
    DateInstallationLuminaire   

FROM(

    SELECT DISTINCT

          E2.ELECLE             AS CodeFoyer
         ,E.ELECLE              AS CodeOuvrage
         ,d.DOMLIBELLE           AS LibDomaine
         ,et.ETYLIBELLE          AS LIB_OUVRAGECAT 
         ,CAT.CTXTEXTE           AS ACCES_OUVRAGE
         ,NRJ_R.NRELIBELLE            AS LIB_REGIME
         ,VE.VENLIBELLE               AS VOIEENT_VOIE
         ,V.VOINATURE                AS NATURE_VOIE
         ,V.VOILIBELLE                AS LIB_VOIE
         ,EC.ELCNUMVOIE                                       AS LIB_VOIEDOM
         ,  S.SECLIBELLE             AS LIB_SECTEUR
         ,  reg.REGLIBELLE           AS LIB_REGION_TECHNIQUE
         , PR.PROLIBELLE                 AS LIB_REGION_ADMIN
         ,MB.MBICLE             AS COD_LUMINAIRE
         ,MB.MBILIBELLE          AS LIB_LUMINAIRE
         ,F.FOUCLE              AS LIB_FOURNISSEUR_LUMINAIRE
         ,CASE                  
            WHEN MAT.MTXBO      OLEEN = 1 
            THEN -1             
          ELSE 0                
          END                   AS XLUMELEC
         ,MB2.MBICLE                AS  COD_LAMPE
         ,MB.MBILIBELLE                      AS LIB_LAMPE
         ,MTF.MTFLIBELLE                                   AS  LIB_LAMPEFAM
         ,NRJC.NCELIBELLE        AS CentreFacturation
         ,NRJ_R.NRECLE          AS CodeRegime
         ,NRJT.NTACLE           AS CodeTarif
         ,NRJT.NTALIBELLE        AS Tarif
         ,ECO.ECOORDRE          AS Ordre
         ,eco.ECODATEINST        AS DateInstallationLuminaire
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VG2.IDPERE ORDER BY VG2.enfantOrdre ASC ) AS nb

    FROM

        ELEMENT E

        INNER JOIN ELEMENTCONTENEUR             EC           ON EC.ID_ELEMENT                = E.ID_ELEMENT 
        INNER JOIN ELEMENTCOMPO                 ECO          ON ECO.ID_ELEMENT               = E.ID_ELEMENT
        INNER JOIN MATBIBLIO                    MB           ON MB.ID_MATBIBLIO              = ECO.ID_MATBIBLIO
        INNER JOIN MATERIELTYPE                 MT           ON MT.ID_MATERIELTYPE           = MB.ID_MATERIELTYPE --AND (MT.ID_MATERIELTYPE = 146)
        INNER JOIN VGRAPHECOMPO                 VG           ON VG.IDPERE                    = ECO.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO
        INNER JOIN VGRAPHECOMPO                 VG2          ON VG2.IDENFANT                 = VG.IDENFANT --AND VG2.ENFANTTYPE = 148
        INNER JOIN ELEMENTCOMPO                 ECO2         ON ECO2.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO         = VG2.IDENFANT
        INNER JOIN MATBIBLIO                    MB2          ON MB2.ID_MATBIBLIO             = ECO2.ID_MATBIBLIO
        --LEFT JOIN VGRAPHECOMPO                    VG3          ON VG3.IDENFANT                 = VG.IDPERE AND VG3.PERETYPE = 145
        --LEFT JOIN ELEMENTCOMPO                  ECO3       ON ECO3.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO         = VG3.IDPERE
        --LEFT JOIN MATBIBLIO                       MB3          ON MB3.ID_MATBIBLIO             = ECO3.ID_MATBIBLIO
        INNER JOIN ELEMENTMATGERE               EMA          ON EMA.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO          = ECO2.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO
        INNER JOIN ELEMENT                      E2           ON E2.ID_ELEMENT                = EMA.ID_ELEMENT
        left JOIN NRJELEMENTCOMPO               NRJ_ECO      ON NRJ_ECO.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO      = ECO2.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO 
        left JOIN NRJREGIME                 NRJ_R        ON NRJ_R.ID_NRJREGIME           = NRJ_ECO.ID_NRJREGIME 
        left JOIN NRJTARIF                     NRJT      ON NRJT.ID_NRJTARIF             = NRJ_ECO.ID_NRJTARIF
        left JOIN NRJCENTREFACTURATION         NRJC      ON NRJC.ID_NRJCENTREFACTURATION = NRJ_ECO.ID_NRJCENTREFACTURATION
        LEFT JOIN MATATTRIBUTSUPP               MAT          ON MAT.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO          = VG.IDPERE --AND mat.ID_MATATTRIBUTSUPPMETA = 555 
        INNER JOIN DOMAINE                     D          ON    E.ID_DOMAINE                =D.ID_DOMAINE AND d.ID_DOMAINE=3
        INNER JOIN ELEMENTTYPE                 ET           ON    EC.ID_ELEMENTTYPE           =ET.ID_ELEMENTTYPE
        LEFT JOIN CATATTRIBUTSUPP             CAT         ON     E.ID_ELEMENT              =CAT.ID_ELEMENT
        INNER JOIN  VOIE                       V          ON      EC.ID_VOIE                =V.ID_VOIE
        INNER JOIN VOIEENTIERE                VE          ON    V.ID_VOIEENTIERE           =VE.ID_VOIEENTIERE
        INNER JOIN SECTEUR                      S          ON   V.ID_SECTEUR                =S.ID_SECTEUR
        INNER JOIN REGION                    REG           ON   S.ID_REGION               =REG.ID_REGION
        LEFT JOIN FOURNISSEUR                 F           ON     E.ID_FOURNISSEUR                   =F.ID_FOURNISSEUR
        INNER JOIN MATFAMILLE                 MTF         ON     MB.ID_MATFAMILLE               = MTF.ID_MATFAMILLE
        INNER JOIN PROPRIETAIRE              PR           ON       EC.ID_PROPRIETAIRE          =PR.ID_PROPRIETAIRE
    ) AS D
WHERE NB = 1
```

---

```
with cte 
as
(
    select  
        p.ID_MATERIELTYPE,
        p.ID_MATBIBLIO,
        CodeLampe,
        LibelleLampe,
        CodeFamilleLampe,
        LibelleFamilleLampe
    from 
        (select distinct
            j.ID_MATERIELTYPE,
            j.ID_MATBIBLIO,
             j.MBICLE                    as CodeLampe
            ,j.MBILIBELLE                as LibelleLampe
            ,j.ID_MATFAMILLE             as CodeFamilleLampe
            ,mf.MTFLIBELLE               as LibelleFamilleLampe
         from MATBIBLIO mbs
            inner join (
                        select 
                            mb.ID_MATBIBLIO ,
                            mb.ID_MATERIELTYPE,
                            mb.ID_MATFAMILLE,
                            mb.MBICLE,
                            mb.MBILIBELLE
                        from MATBIBLIO mb
                        where ID_MATERIELTYPE in (  select
                                                        ID_MATERIELTYPE
                                                    from 
                                                        MATERIELTYPE mt
                                                    where 
                                                        ID_DOMAINE = 1 and mt.MTYLIBELLE like '%lampe%'
                                                 )
                        )  j on mbs.ID_MATBIBLIO = j.ID_MATBIBLIO
            inner join MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA supmeta on mbs.ID_MATERIELTYPE    = supmeta.ID_MATERIELTYPE
            left join MATBIBLIOSUPPMETAVALEUR v  on v.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA = supmeta.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA
            inner join MATFAMILLE mf             on mf.ID_MATFAMILLE       = j.ID_MATFAMILLE
            group by    
                j.ID_MATBIBLIO ,
                j.ID_MATERIELTYPE,
                j.ID_MATFAMILLE,
                j.MBILIBELLE,
                mf.MTFLIBELLE,
                j.MBICLE,
                supmeta.MABNOM,
                supmeta.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA
        ) as p
)
select 
    CodeLampe,
    LibelleLampe,
    CodeFamilleLampe,
    LibelleFamilleLampe,
    coalesce(mbsPN.[MBXTEXTE],mbsPN.[MBXENTIER],mbsPN.[MBXREEL])         as PuissanceNominaleWatt,
    coalesce(mbsPCFW.[MBXTEXTE],mbsPCFW.[MBXENTIER],mbsPCFW.[MBXREEL])   as PuissanceConsommeeFerroWatt,
    coalesce(mbsPCEW.[MBXTEXTE],mbsPCEW.[MBXENTIER],mbsPCEW.[MBXREEL])   as PuissanceConsommeeElecWatt,
    coalesce(mbsF.[MBXTEXTE],mbsF.[MBXENTIER],mbsF.[MBXREEL])            as FluxLampe,
    v.MBVLIBELLE                                                         as ClasseLampe
from cte
    left join [MATBIBLIOSUPP] mbsPN     on mbsPN.ID_MATBIBLIO   = cte.ID_MATBIBLIO and mbsPN.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA   = 1323
    left join [MATBIBLIOSUPP] mbsPCFW   on mbsPCFW.ID_MATBIBLIO = cte.ID_MATBIBLIO and mbsPCFW.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA = 1383 
    left join [MATBIBLIOSUPP] mbsPCEW   on mbsPCEW.ID_MATBIBLIO = cte.ID_MATBIBLIO and mbsPCEW.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA = 1398 
    left join [MATBIBLIOSUPP] mbsF      on mbsF.ID_MATBIBLIO    = cte.ID_MATBIBLIO and mbsF.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA    = 1324 
    left join MATBIBLIOSUPPMETAVALEUR v on v.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETAVALEUR = 
        (select MBXENTIER from MATBIBLIOSUPP where ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA = 1322 and ID_MATBIBLIO = cte.ID_MATBIBLIO)
```

Comment: `Union` requires that all of the results being combined have the same columns. It appears that you want to combine result sets that have wildly different column lists. What do you expect as a final result?

Answer (score 0):

I think the queries are upside down.  Below is a reworked query with some commentary.

```
with cte as (
    select p.ID_MATERIELTYPE
    , p.ID_MATBIBLIO
    , CodeLampe
    , LibelleLampe
    , CodeFamilleLampe
    , LibelleFamilleLampe
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT j.ID_MATERIELTYPE
        , j.ID_MATBIBLIO
        , j.MBICLE as CodeLampe
        , j.MBILIBELLE as LibelleLampe
        , j.ID_MATFAMILLE as CodeFamilleLampe
        , mf.MTFLIBELLE as LibelleFamilleLampe
        FROM MATBIBLIO mbs
        INNER JOIN (
                    select mb.ID_MATBIBLIO ,
                    mb.ID_MATERIELTYPE,
                    mb.ID_MATFAMILLE,
                    mb.MBICLE,
                    mb.MBILIBELLE
                    from MATBIBLIO mb
                    /* Whhere the ID is in the subquery.  The subquery should return more than 1 result, but 1 is okay, too. */
                    where ID_MATERIELTYPE in (
                                            select ID_MATERIELTYPE
                                            from MATERIELTYPE mt
                                            where ID_DOMAINE = 1 
                                            /* PATINDEX() will help to find records better than like */
                                            /* If a value over 0 is returned, then the value to match was found. */
                                            and PATINDEX('%lampe%', mt.MTYLIBELLE) > '0'
                                             )
                        ) AS j on mbs.ID_MATBIBLIO = j.ID_MATBIBLIO
            inner join MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA AS supmeta on mbs.ID_MATERIELTYPE = supmeta.ID_MATERIELTYPE
            left join MATBIBLIOSUPPMETAVALEUR AS v on v.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA = supmeta.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA
            inner join MATFAMILLE AS mf ON mf.ID_MATFAMILLE = j.ID_MATFAMILLE
            --group by j.ID_MATBIBLIO ,
            --j.ID_MATERIELTYPE,
            --j.ID_MATFAMILLE,
            --j.MBILIBELLE,
            --mf.MTFLIBELLE,
            --j.MBICLE,
            --supmeta.MABNOM,
            --supmeta.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA
        ) as p
)
select CodeLampe
,   LibelleLampe
,   CodeFamilleLampe
,   LibelleFamilleLampe
    /* COALESCE(a, b) <- if a is NULL, then b will be used.  If a and b are NULL, then NULL is returned. */
,   COALESCE(mbsPN.[MBXTEXTE],mbsPN.[MBXENTIER],mbsPN.[MBXREEL]) as PuissanceNominaleWatt
,   COALESCE(mbsPCFW.[MBXTEXTE],mbsPCFW.[MBXENTIER],mbsPCFW.[MBXREEL]) as PuissanceConsommeeFerroWatt
,   COALESCE(mbsPCEW.[MBXTEXTE],mbsPCEW.[MBXENTIER],mbsPCEW.[MBXREEL]) as PuissanceConsommeeElecWatt
,   COALESCE(mbsF.[MBXTEXTE],mbsF.[MBXENTIER],mbsF.[MBXREEL]) as FluxLampe
,   v.MBVLIBELLE as ClasseLampe
,    NULL AS CodeFoyer
,    NULL AS CodeOuvrage
,    NULL AS LibDomaine
,    NULL AS LIB_OUVRAGECAT
--,  NULL AS POSE_OUVRAGE
,    NULL AS ACCES_OUVRAGE
--,  NULL AS DIVERS_OUVRAGE
--,  NULL AS OBSERVATION_OUVRAGE
,    NULL AS LIB_REGIME
,    NULL AS VOIEENT_VOIE
--,  NULL AS NUMVOIE_OUVRAGE
,    NULL AS NATURE_VOIE
,    NULL AS LIB_VOIE
,    NULL AS LIB_VOIEDOM
,    NULL AS LIB_SECTEUR
,    NULL AS LIB_REGION_TECHNIQUE
,    NULL AS LIB_REGION_ADMIN
,    NULL AS COD_LUMINAIRE
,    NULL AS LIB_LUMINAIRE
,    NULL AS LIB_FOURNISSEUR_LUMINAIRE
,    NULL AS XLUMELEC
,    NULL AS COD_LAMPE
,    NULL AS LIB_LAMPE
,    NULL AS LIB_LAMPEFAM
,    NULL AS Ordre
,    NULL AS DateInstallationLuminaire
from cte
left join [MATBIBLIOSUPP] mbsPN on mbsPN.ID_MATBIBLIO = cte.ID_MATBIBLIO and mbsPN.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA = 1323
left join [MATBIBLIOSUPP] mbsPCFW on mbsPCFW.ID_MATBIBLIO = cte.ID_MATBIBLIO and mbsPCFW.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA = 1383 
left join [MATBIBLIOSUPP] mbsPCEW on mbsPCEW.ID_MATBIBLIO = cte.ID_MATBIBLIO and mbsPCEW.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA = 1398 
left join [MATBIBLIOSUPP] mbsF on mbsF.ID_MATBIBLIO  = cte.ID_MATBIBLIO and mbsF.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA = 1324
left join MATBIBLIOSUPPMETAVALEUR v on v.ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETAVALEUR = (
                                                            select MBXENTIER
                                                            from MATBIBLIOSUPP
                                                            where ID_MATBIBLIOSUPPMETA = 1322
                                                            and ID_MATBIBLIO = cte.ID_MATBIBLIO)
-- Union results from CTE with the query below
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
NULL AS CodeLampe
,   NULL AS LibelleLampe
,   NULL AS CodeFamilleLampe
,   NULL AS LibelleFamilleLampe
,   NULL AS  PuissanceNominaleWatt
,   NULL AS  PuissanceConsommeeFerroWatt
,   NULL AS  PuissanceConsommeeElecWatt
,   NULL AS FluxLampe
,   NULL AS ClasseLampe
,   CodeFoyer
,   CodeOuvrage
,   LibDomaine
,   LIB_OUVRAGECAT
--, POSE_OUVRAGE
,   ACCES_OUVRAGE
--, DIVERS_OUVRAGE
--, OBSERVATION_OUVRAGE
,   LIB_REGIME
,   VOIEENT_VOIE
--, NUMVOIE_OUVRAGE
,   NATURE_VOIE
,   LIB_VOIE
,   LIB_VOIEDOM
,   LIB_SECTEUR
,   LIB_REGION_TECHNIQUE
,   LIB_REGION_ADMIN
,   COD_LUMINAIRE
,   LIB_LUMINAIRE
,   LIB_FOURNISSEUR_LUMINAIRE
,   XLUMELEC
,   COD_LAMPE
,   LIB_LAMPE
,   LIB_LAMPEFAM
,   Ordre
,   DateInstallationLuminaire 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT E2.ELECLE AS CodeFoyer
    , E.ELECLE AS CodeOuvrage
    , d.DOMLIBELLE AS LibDomaine
    , et.ETYLIBELLE AS LIB_OUVRAGECAT 
    , CAT.CTXTEXTE AS ACCES_OUVRAGE
    , NRJ_R.NRELIBELLE AS LIB_REGIME
    , VE.VENLIBELLE AS VOIEENT_VOIE
    , V.VOINATURE AS NATURE_VOIE
    , V.VOILIBELLE AS LIB_VOIE
    , EC.ELCNUMVOIE AS LIB_VOIEDOM
    , S.SECLIBELLE AS LIB_SECTEUR
    , reg.REGLIBELLE AS LIB_REGION_TECHNIQUE
    , PR.PROLIBELLE AS LIB_REGION_ADMIN
    , MB.MBICLE AS COD_LUMINAIRE
    , MB.MBILIBELLE AS LIB_LUMINAIRE
    , F.FOUCLE AS LIB_FOURNISSEUR_LUMINAIRE
    ,CASE WHEN MAT.MTXBOOLEEN = '1' THEN '-1' ELSE '0' END AS [XLUMELEC]
    ,MB2.MBICLE AS  COD_LAMPE
    ,MB.MBILIBELLE AS LIB_LAMPE
    ,MTF.MTFLIBELLE AS  LIB_LAMPEFAM
    ,NRJC.NCELIBELLE AS CentreFacturation
    ,NRJ_R.NRECLE AS CodeRegime
    ,NRJT.NTACLE AS CodeTarif
    ,NRJT.NTALIBELLE AS Tarif
    ,ECO.ECOORDRE AS Ordre
    ,eco.ECODATEINST AS DateInstallationLuminaire
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VG2.IDPERE ORDER BY VG2.enfantOrdre ASC) AS nb
    FROM ELEMENT AS E
    INNER JOIN ELEMENTCONTENEUR AS EC ON EC.ID_ELEMENT = E.ID_ELEMENT 
    INNER JOIN ELEMENTCOMPO AS ECO ON ECO.ID_ELEMENT = E.ID_ELEMENT
    INNER JOIN MATBIBLIO AS MB ON MB.ID_MATBIBLIO = ECO.ID_MATBIBLIO
    INNER JOIN MATERIELTYPE AS MT ON MT.ID_MATERIELTYPE = MB.ID_MATERIELTYPE --AND (MT.ID_MATERIELTYPE = 146)
    INNER JOIN VGRAPHECOMPO AS VG ON VG.IDPERE = ECO.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO
    INNER JOIN VGRAPHECOMPO AS VG2 ON VG2.IDENFANT = VG.IDENFANT --AND VG2.ENFANTTYPE = 148
    INNER JOIN ELEMENTCOMPO AS ECO2 ON ECO2.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO = VG2.IDENFANT
    INNER JOIN MATBIBLIO AS MB2 ON MB2.ID_MATBIBLIO = ECO2.ID_MATBIBLIO
    --LEFT JOIN VGRAPHECOMPO AS VG3 ON VG3.IDENFANT = VG.IDPERE AND VG3.PERETYPE = 145
    --LEFT JOIN ELEMENTCOMPO AS ECO3 ON ECO3.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO = VG3.IDPERE
    --LEFT JOIN MATBIBLIO AS MB3 ON MB3.ID_MATBIBLIO = ECO3.ID_MATBIBLIO
    INNER JOIN ELEMENTMATGERE AS EMA ON EMA.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO = ECO2.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO
    INNER JOIN ELEMENT AS E2 ON E2.ID_ELEMENT = EMA.ID_ELEMENT
    left JOIN NRJELEMENTCOMPO AS NRJ_ECO ON NRJ_ECO.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO = ECO2.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO 
    left JOIN NRJREGIME AS NRJ_R ON NRJ_R.ID_NRJREGIME = NRJ_ECO.ID_NRJREGIME 
    left JOIN NRJTARIF AS NRJT ON NRJT.ID_NRJTARIF = NRJ_ECO.ID_NRJTARIF
    left JOIN NRJCENTREFACTURATION AS NRJC ON NRJC.ID_NRJCENTREFACTURATION = NRJ_ECO.ID_NRJCENTREFACTURATION
    LEFT JOIN MATATTRIBUTSUPP AS MAT ON MAT.ID_ELEMENTCOMPO = VG.IDPERE --AND mat.ID_MATATTRIBUTSUPPMETA = 555 
    INNER JOIN DOMAINE AS D ON  E.ID_DOMAINE =D.ID_DOMAINE AND d.ID_DOMAINE=3
    INNER JOIN ELEMENTTYPE AS ET ON EC.ID_ELEMENTTYPE =ET.ID_ELEMENTTYPE
    LEFT JOIN CATATTRIBUTSUPP AS CAT ON  E.ID_ELEMENT =CAT.ID_ELEMENT
    INNER JOIN  VOIE AS V ON EC.ID_VOIE =V.ID_VOIE
    INNER JOIN VOIEENTIERE AS VE ON V.ID_VOIEENTIERE =VE.ID_VOIEENTIERE
    INNER JOIN SECTEUR AS S ON V.ID_SECTEUR = S.ID_SECTEUR
    INNER JOIN REGION AS REG ON S.ID_REGION = REG.ID_REGION
    LEFT JOIN FOURNISSEUR AS F ON E.ID_FOURNISSEUR = F.ID_FOURNISSEUR
    INNER JOIN MATFAMILLE AS MTF ON MB.ID_MATFAMILLE = MTF.ID_MATFAMILLE
    INNER JOIN PROPRIETAIRE AS PR ON EC.ID_PROPRIETAIRE =PR.ID_PROPRIETAIRE
    ) AS D
WHERE NB = 1 



--Resulting columns
/*
CodeLampe,
LibelleLampe,
CodeFamilleLampe,
LibelleFamilleLampe,
PuissanceNominaleWatt,
PuissanceConsommeeFerroWatt,
PuissanceConsommeeElecWatt,
FluxLampe,
ClasseLampe,
CodeFoyer,
CodeOuvrage,
LibDomaine,
LIB_OUVRAGECAT,
ACCES_OUVRAGE,
LIB_REGIME,
VOIEENT_VOIE,
NATURE_VOIE,
LIB_VOIE,
LIB_VOIEDOM,
LIB_SECTEUR,
LIB_REGION_TECHNIQUE,
LIB_REGION_ADMIN,
COD_LUMINAIRE,
LIB_LUMINAIRE,
LIB_FOURNISSEUR_LUMINAIRE,
XLUMELEC,
COD_LAMPE,
LIB_LAMPE,
LIB_LAMPEFAM,
Ordre,
DateInstallationLuminaire 
*/
```

Comment: How do you `union` 9 columns with 22 columns and get 31 columns without explicitly padding both select lists out to 31 columns? Sayeth the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "The following are basic rules for combining the result sets of two queries by using UNION: • The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all queries. • The data types must be compatible."

Comment: Good point.  I updated the query if you'd like to look it over again.

Comment: thank you,  the query returns a result but only the result of the first query( the cte), the rest are nulls. It doesn't take in consideration these columns : CodeFoyer,
CodeOuvrage,
LibDomaine,
LIB_OUVRAGECAT,
ACCES_OUVRAGE,
LIB_REGIME,
VOIEENT_VOIE,
NATURE_VOIE,
LIB_VOIE,
LIB_VOIEDOM,
LIB_SECTEUR,
LIB_REGION_TECHNIQUE,
LIB_REGION_ADMIN,
COD_LUMINAIRE,
LIB_LUMINAIRE,
LIB_FOURNISSEUR_LUMINAIRE,
XLUMELEC,
COD_LAMPE,
LIB_LAMPE,
LIB_LAMPEFAM,
Ordre,
DateInstallationLuminaire

Comment: yes, you're right but do you think there is any other way of combining the result set of two complex queries without using temp tables (i don't have the permission to)